# Download files from S3 in parallel (AWS .NET SDK)

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I can't get `AmazonS3Client.GetObject` to download files in parallel. The code is as follows:

```cs
public async Task<string> ReadFile(string filename)
{
    string filePath = config.RootFolderPath + filename;
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Console.WriteLine(filePath + " - start");
    using (var response = await s3Client.GetObjectAsync(config.Bucket, filePath))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(filePath + " - request - " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.ResponseStream))
        {
            return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

This is called like this:

```cs
var tasks = (from file in files select ReadFile(file)).ToArray();
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

This results that the requests are returned sequentially (not in order though). I read about 50 tiny files, so that takes about 25 seconds hanging in method `GetObjectAsync` for the last read. Instead I hoped that I can read the 50 files in 2-3 seconds.

I've already verified:

1. I'm on the task pool. So the synchronization context isn't in the mix. I also added a `ConfigureAwait(false)` to the tasks, but that didn't make a difference as expected.
2. I've tried various settings with the `AmazonS3Client`, like using the HTTP protocol or changing the buffer size. Without success.
3. I added a stop watch to verify the problem isn't around reading the response stream. However, when not reading the response stream, the whole method returns quickly.

Comment: @Kobi or OP, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @Timo - I didn't have the same problem, but this might help: [GetObjectRequest hangs randomly](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/152#issuecomment-152130910) - the whole thread has many solutions that might help.